# Dspace, unable to create an user or edit profile of current user via web interface

Tags: dspace

I want to create an user via My dsapce ->New user.
I receive the email to complete Registration. But when I fill the form, get the ‘Internal System Error’.
The environment:
DSpace version:  5.0-rc4-SNAPSHOT, 
tomcat7, 
Postgresql 9.3 
java version "1.7.0_65" , 
OS:  Linux(amd64) version 3.13.0-32-generic

Here is the error log in  dspace/log/dspace.log :

```
2015-01-01 21:54:48,220 INFO  org.dspace.browse.BrowseEngine @ xxx@yahoo.com:session_id=6D06ED6F708F84A7BFFB443D5FEA2D1F:ip_addr=192.168.2.150:browse_mini:
2015-01-01 21:54:48,242 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.DiscoverUtility @ facets for scope, null: 3
2015-01-01 21:54:52,149 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.EditProfileServlet @ xxx@yahoo.com:session_id=6D06ED6F708F84A7BFFB443D5FEA2D1F:ip_addr=192.168.2.150:view_profile:
2015-01-01 21:55:14,082 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.EditProfileServlet @ xxx@yahoo.com:session_id=6D06ED6F708F84A7BFFB443D5FEA2D1F:ip_addr=192.168.2.150:edit_profile:password_changed=true
2015-01-01 21:55:14,082 INFO  org.dspace.eperson.EPerson @ xxx@yahoo.com:session_id=6D06ED6F708F84A7BFFB443D5FEA2D1F:ip_addr=192.168.2.150:update_eperson:eperson_id=1
2015-01-01 21:55:14,092 WARN  org.dspace.content.DSpaceObject @ Invalid metadata field: [eperson.lastname] : [aaa]
2015-01-01 21:55:14,092 WARN  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet @ xxx@yahoo.com:session_id=6D06ED6F708F84A7BFFB443D5FEA2D1F:ip_addr=192.168.2.150:database_error:java.sql.SQLException\colon; Invalid metadata field\colon; [eperson.lastname]
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid metadata field: [eperson.lastname]
        at org.dspace.content.DSpaceObject.updateMetadata(DSpaceObject.java:122)
        at org.dspace.eperson.EPerson.update(EPerson.java:1056)
        at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.EditProfileServlet.doDSPost(EditProfileServlet.java:88)
        at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.processRequest(DSpaceServlet.java:115)
        at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.doPost(DSpaceServlet.java:73)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.dspace.app.webui.filter.RegisteredOnlyFilter.doFilter(RegisteredOnlyFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is this a fresh install or an upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Please try a fresh install, as I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on http://demo.dspace.org

The error you are seeing is very likely related to the new DSpace 5 functionality "Metadata for all DSpace Objects" that made some changes to the Eperson object as well.

https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-1582

If you are running the DSpace 5 codebase, on a pre-DSpace 5 initiated database, this kind of error could arise. Reversely, you could be seeing similar things if you are running pre-DSpace 5 code, on a DSpace 5 database.